# How do I test for NULL with a full outer join?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table named TabOne containing those columns
Id Date Price description

```
+----+-------------------------------+--------------+---------+
| id | Date                          |   Price      | descri  |
+----+-------------------------------+--------------+---------+
| 1  |2014-05-05                     |    10         |     bab|
| 2  |2014-05-05                     |    50         |     bab|
| 3  |2014-05-05                     |    50         |     bab|
| 1  |2014-05-04                     |    60         |     bab|
| 4  |2014-05-04                     |    60         |     bab|
| 5  |2014-05-04                     |    70         |     bab|
| 6  |2014-05-04                     |    70         |     bab|
|    |                               |               |        |
+----+-------------------------------+--------------+---------+
```

I have to compare Prices between two dates, and if an entry in a date have not an eqivalent in the other date I must show it also

```
+----+-------------------------------+--------------+---------+
| id |                               |   Diff       | descri  |
+----+-------------------------------+--------------+---------+
| 1  | 2014-05-05 2014-05-04         |    60-10      |     bab|
| 2  | 2014-05-05                    |    Null       |     bab|
| 3  | 2014-05-05                    |    Null       |     bab|
| 4  | 2014-05-04                    |    Null       |     bab|
| 5  | 2014-05-04                    |    Null       |     bab|
| 6  | 2014-05-04                    |    Null       |     bab|
|    |                               |               |        |
+----+-------------------------------+--------------+---------+

2014-05-05
2014-05-04
```

so I wrote :

```
Select tabOne.Price - TO.Price from TabOne
Full outer JOIN TabOne as TO on TO.id = TabOne.id and TO.Date='2014-05-04'
where TabOne.Date='2014-05-05'
```

but it keeps shoing me just Id existing on `2014-05-05`

```
+----+-------------------------------+--------------+---------+
| id |                               |   Diff       | descri  |
+----+-------------------------------+--------------+---------+
| 1  |                               |    60-10     |     bab |
+----+-------------------------------+--------------+---------+
```

Comment: That's because after you do your full outer join, the where clause is applied

Comment: so what must I do , I have to compare between 2 dates !

Comment: You might want to refine your question, it's not making any sense the way I am reading it.   You want to show "those" with NULL price.  And yet in your sample query, you are doing subtraction, and not making any attempt to check for NULL.   If you could post exact expected results for your sample data, that would make it clearer.

Comment: Can you post the desired output?  In reading your post, I think you are asking to return each ID that does not have a matching ID with the other date (so basically, IDs 2,3,4,5,6).  Or are you only looking for those that don't have a matching ID for the next date (4,5,6) or the previous date (2,3)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question is not very clear. I guess you want something like this. Test and adjust to your needs:

```
; WITH a AS
    ( SELECT t.Id, t.Price
      FROM TabOne AS t
      WHERE t.Date = '20140505'
    ) ,
  b AS
    ( SELECT t.Id, t.Price
      FROM TabOne AS t
      WHERE t.Date = '20140504'
    ) 
SELECT 
    Id = COALESCE(a.Id, b.Id),
    PriceA = a.Price,
    PriceB = b.Price,
    Diff = a.Price - b.Price 
FROM 
    a FULL JOIN b
        ON  a.id = b.id ;
```

Test at **[SQL-Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8689e/6)**

The original query does not work like this due to the `where TabOne.Date='2014-05-05'`. That basically converts the `FULL` join to a `LEFT` join (as a column of the left table is used in the WHERE condition).

Comment: Thks, your solution is perfect , but what i don't undrestand is why my solution didn't work , it seems to be correct !

Answer (score -3):

try this

```
  Select tabOne.Price - TO.Price from TabOne tabOne
  Full outer JOIN TabOne as TO on TO.id = TabOne.id 
  where TabOne.Date='2014-05-05'and TO.Date = '2014-05-04'
```